# How to subtract two bitsets in c++

Tags: c++, bitset

I have 2 [bitsets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) each one storing 100 bits. How to subtract them, treating them as unsigned numbers?

Comment: What would subtraction mean? Do you want to treat the two sets as two 100-bit numbers?

Answer (score 10):

If you mean to clear all bits in first operand witch are sets in other one, you need to make a binnary and with negated second operand:

```
std::bitset<10> first (string("1001001001"));
std::bitset<10> second (string("1001000000"));

cout << (first & ~second) << endl;
```

Comment: It would be worth noted that this solution isn't *substracting*. It might be more meaningful in a bitset context than mere substraction, but as Neil asked you can never know the real intend.

Comment: I think this guess is right, but if what is wanted is bitwise modulo subtraction, then that's the same thing as bitwise addition: XOR. So `first ^ second`. 0 - 1 = 1, 1 - 0 = 1, 1 - 1 = 0, 0 - 0 = 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're referring to a 128-bit integer number, and are attempting to subtract 2 128bit ints. I'd recommend googling for BigNum - a library which is designed to handle LARGE numbers. The functionality you're after is probably already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

convert both bitsets to unsigned long, using the to ulong (unsigned long) method of std::bitset, subtract the unsigned longs then use the subtraction result construct a new bitset from the result.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{

   std::bitset<10> b1 ( 77 );
   std::bitset<10> b2 ( 55 );

   unsigned long diff = b1.to_ulong() - b2.to_ulong();
   std::bitset<10> result( diff );
   std::cout << diff << std::endl;
   std::cout << result << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: He said the bitsets were of size 100, not 10.

Comment: I was just giving an example.

Comment: How does he scale up from 10 to 100? The example as it stands is worthless.